# How can I fix sub-index in math?

Tags: math-mode

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Werner's Solution
\newcommand{\dotI}{\vphantom{I}\smash{\dot{I}}}
\newcommand{\ddotO}{\vphantom{I}\smash{\ddot{O}}}
\newcommand{\BreG}{\vphantom{I}\smash{\breve{G}}}

\begin{document}
$E_{\dotI}=E_P+E_K$

$E_{\ddotO}=E_P+E_K$

$E_{\BreG}=E_P+E_K$
\end{document}
```

**Edited:**

How can I create the following picture?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest `$E_{\vphantom{I}\smash{\dot{I}}} = E_P + E_K$` instead. Perhaps `\newcommand{\dotI}{\vphantom{I}\smash{\dot{I}}}`.

Comment: `\textit` will make full size, not subscript text unless you load `amsmath`

Comment: I understand that in Turkish the upper case version of `i` is `İ`, but in math there is no prescribed relationship between upper case and lower case letters. Readers will mistake `İ` in a subscript with “dotted `I`”, so `I` with some operation performed on it.

Comment: @egreg, You're right. Similar "ÖÜŞÇĞ". Will it be treated as we add these letters?

Comment: @Özgür If those subscripts are *textual*, they should appear upright.

Comment: I've updated my question according to your solutions. Will you please see?

Answer (score 1):

Using declaration of new commands for **C-cedilla**, like

```
\newcommand{\cediC}{\vphantom{I}\smash{\mathit{\c{C}}}}
```

We can use the customized command `\cediC` in math mode:

```
$E_{\cediC}=E_P+E_K$
```

To get

[image: *enter image description here*]

However, it would be simpler to declare the following in preamble.

```
\providecommand{\cediC}{\mathit{\c{C}}}
```